# Hide fixed div when footer is in view and show when footer isnt in view? (jQuery function)

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, fixed

I have a query where i have a fixed div with contact details that i would like to be on show until the footer is in view then it will fadeout. When the footer is out of view when the user scrolls up, the fixed div then fadesIn. I have had a look at some examples and using my own div tags and styling and nothing happens. An example i have used is:

```
$('#footer').appear();  
   $('#footer').on('appear', function(){
      $('#fixed_div').fadeOut();
});

$('#footer').on('disappear', function(){
   $('#fixed_div').fadeIn();
});
```

HTML-BASIC

```
<div id="footer">
   <div class="footer-wrapper">
      Footer details here
   </div>
</div>

<div id="fixed_div">
   <ul>
       <li><h1>details here</h1></li>
       <li><h1>details here</h2></li>
   </ul>  
</div>
```

CSS -

```
#call_to_action {
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    padding:5px 0px 8px;
    width:100%;
    background:#000;
    z-index:3000;
}

#footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-width:320px;
    color:#FFF;
    background:#000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Footer is my main footer at the bottom and the fixed div is positioned at the bottom:0; when the user scrolls.

Can anyone advise me to where i am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: give us some html code

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script like this:

```
var secondval = $('#footer').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){    
   var firstval = $(document).scrollTop();

   if(firstval >= secondval)
   {
      $('#fixed_div').fadeOut();
   }

});
```

Comment: Hi @edonbajrami, i have looked at your snippet of code and added in an else statement (fadeIn) at the bottom which works but the fixed div seems to fade in and out not exactly at the footer but on the last article of my blog (i'm using Wordpress). Also firefox doesn't like this function (typical!) Is there another way of detecting when to fadeIn/Out? Thanks for your help :)